# How to add new products through magento database?

Tags: mysql, magento, triggers

I am trying to bring products from mysql database to magento database. Could you please help which tables i have to insert the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not so easy. You should build a migration script and use magento API to do that. There’s a lot of relations between tables in database and without good understanding what happened there I really do not recommend your approach.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101152/what-are-the-main-tables-that-updated-when-we-creating-new-product-in-magento

I have mapped this tables but still unable to get data.

Comment: I am using sql triggers to insert the data, i don't need to insert all datas.